# problemas con `cat` en bash

Tags: bash

Tengo un problema lo que deseo es utilizar un `cat` para juntar cientos de archivos que tengo en distintos folders que están por días, que a su vez este tiene sub-folders.

La siguiente linea de código que lo que tiene que hacer es
juntar todos los archivos que empiecen con `_1_1.msd` en uno solo pero no funciona a continuación el código utilizado:

```
find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/*/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_1.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_1_b850.msd ; done  ;
```

Se que este es para un solo archivo, pero es como lo estaba haciendo pero no funciono y 
lo que hice fue hacerlo de la siguiente manera que es muy tediosa, haciendo una instrucción por cada día.

```
    #para folder_1 dia 2015167
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_1.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_1_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_2.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_2_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_3.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_3_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_4.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_4_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_5.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_5_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_6.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_6_b850.msd ; done  

    #para folder_9 dia 2015167
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_1.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_1_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_2.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_2_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_3.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_3_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_4.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_4_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_5.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_5_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015167/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_6.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_6_b850.msd ; done 
   #para folder_1 dia 2015168
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_1.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_1_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_2.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_2_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_3.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_3_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_4.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_4_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_5.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_5_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_1_6.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_1_6_b850.msd ; done  

    #para folder_9 dia 2015168
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_1.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_1_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_2.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_2_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_3.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_3_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_4.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_4_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_5.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_5_b850.msd ; done  
            find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_6.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_6_b850.msd ; done
```

Alguna Sugerencia?

Comment: Hola, ¿cual es la razón de usar `cat`? En vez de usarlo y redireccionar el output puedes copiar el archivo a la ruta destino con un `cp`

Comment: podrías compartirnos la salida de por lo menos uno de los comandos usando la opción `set -x`, por ejemplo, la salida de la siguiente línea: `set -x; find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/2015168/b8/folder_9/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read d; do dname=$(basename $d); cat "$d/$dname"*_9_1.msd > /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/"$dname"_9_1_b850.msd ; done  ;set +x`

Comment: Supongo que te darás cuenta de que al procesar el directorio 2015168 se pisa el archivo escrito al procesar el directorio 2015167.
Estoy seguro de que no es eso lo que querés, así que describí un poco más la tarea. ¿Se ejecuta una vez por día, en un directorio?, etc.

Comment: Usando `cat ... > nuevo_archivo` lo está reescribiendo cada vez, por lo que lo único que quedará en el archivo final es lo leído en el último fichero. Nótese también que puedes utilizar `-exec` para ejecutar cosas directamente con el resultado de `find` --> `find ... -type d -exec cat {}/1_2 >> mi_archivo \;`.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes intentar con algo parecido a

```
find /media/user/PENDRIVE/DATA/B850/*/b8/folder_1/*_1_1.msd -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -exec cat {} >> /ruta/archivo.concentrado \;
```